# fetch datausing jsonp in php from server

Tags: php, json, jsonp

fetch data using jsonp in php from server

i have written like this

```
$.getJSON('http://www.globalprompt.org/sg/cio/vendor2/list_vendor/?callback=?', function(vendor_data) {
         $.each(vendor_data, function() {
           $.each(this, function(k, v) {
           console.log( "<Li id='" + k + "'>" + v + "</Li>" );

           });
         });
    });

}
```

but it get only last record not all records

i want all record from that json file

Answer (score 1):

The server side code isn't returning real JSONP.

It puts in a separate function call for each record instead of a single function call with an array as the argument.

You need to fix this on the server.

It also sends the data with `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `Content-Type: application/javascript`, which you should address at the same time.

Comment: The code that provides the response to `http://www.globalprompt.org/sg/cio/vendor2/list_vendor/?callback=?` is already on a server. It is just broken.

Comment: yeah ,i know that but it returns only one record but on server it contains too many records in json format

Comment: @NikhilMusale — No, it doesn't. Please reread the first two paragraphs of this answer.